# Расширение базовых типов

Tags: c#

Есть задача в расширении базового типа string. Суть в том, что бы строка принимала разное значение в зависимости от страны пользователя, тобишь мне нужно сделать так, строка должна хранить ID локализованной строки, при попытке взять значение строки возвращалось локализованная строка. Проблема в том, что нужно это интегрировать в уже законченную среду без её изменения.

Comment: И что же вы сделали сами?

Comment: В каком смысле?

Comment: В прямом. Что вы сделали для решения этой задачи? Вы же не предлагаете решить ее за вас целиком?

Comment: Нет, не в коем случае. Пока что я смог найти методы расширения, которые частично подходят для моей задачи. Но дело в том, что я не знаю возможно ли вообще как то перегрузить операцию взятия значения из переменной с помощью них.

Comment: хорошо, давайте тогда подробнее. У вас это реальная задача, или учебное задание? И что вы подразумеваете под перегрузкой операции взятия значения?

Comment: И то и то. Работаю над своим не большим проектом. Пишу расширение для Unity3D для того что бы использовать локализацию. Допустим там есть класс GUIContent который текст хранит в поле типа string. Мне нужно каким то образом сделать без изменения это класса так, что бы когда он брал для своих нужд этот тест из переменной сначала вызывался мой код, который отдавал бы эту строку на определённом языке. Грубый пример:

string SomeStr = "check_button_text";

Localization.SetCountyCode("ru");

print(SomeStr); //Выведит проверить

Localization.SetCountyCode("en");

print(SomeStr); //Выведит check

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы решаете задачу локализации. Скажу сразу, добавить локализацию без изменения окружающего кода — задача утопическая, и если она поставлена вам в таком виде, решения не имеет. Так и объясните постановщикам задачи. Так что переделывать код придётся, и то, что архитектор не заложил этого в дизайн — его личный фэйл.

Теперь по поводу того, как же правильно делать локализацию. Я расскажу вкратце на примере WPF, для WinForms делается аналогично.

Итак, вы должны найти все строки, которые выводятся программой, и поместить их в `ResourceDictionary`. Эти же строки, но на других языках, необходимо скомпилировать в отдельные DLL (по штуке на язык) с именем `<Appname>.resources.dll` (`<Appname>` замените на имя файла вашего модуля), и помещены в соответствующие подкаталоги: английский в подкаталог `en-US`, русский в `ru-RU`, китайский в `zh-CN` и т. д. Эти DLL будут автоматически загружены WPF-фреймворком, и заменят строки из `ResourceDictionary`, о котором говорилось в начале этого абзаца.

В вашем UI всякий код вида `<Label>Enter password:</Label>` надо заменить на `<Label Content="{DynamicResource ID_ENTERPASSWORD}"/>` (или посемантичнее: `<Label Content="{DynamicResource 'UI.Authentication.PasswordRequest'}"/>`, если хотите.) Более сложный код, который «складывает» строку из кусочков, должен брать кусочки не как константы, а через `App.FindResources("resource id here")`. (Заметьте, при этом строки получатся статическими; для смены языка на лету вам понадобятся дополнительные трюки.)

Большой [tutorial с примерами](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms788718.aspx) лежит на MSDN.

Часто возникающие проблемы:

- Тексты на разных языках имеют разную длину и занимают разное количество места. Будьте готовы к тому, что ваша вёрстка, «заточенная» под английский язык, разлезется. Будьте готовы к тому, что некоторые однострочные тексты на немецком или финском будут занимать две-три строчки. Китайские иероглифы обычно в среднем выше латиницы и кириллицы.
- Особенный кайф — поддержка [RTL-языков](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-to-left): иврита и арабского.
- Одна и та же строка на английском может в зависимости от контекста иметь разные переводы на русский. Например: «new» иногда переводится как «новый», а иногда как «создать документ». Закладывайте все возможные контексты в разные ID, не скупитесь на комментарии для переводчиков.
- В разных языках есть такие неприятности, как склонения и спряжения, роды, падежи и числа. И разный порядок слов в предложении. Сравните:

  - английский: 1 file, 2 files, 5 files, 12 files
  - русский: 1 файл, 2 файл**а**, 5 файл**ов**, 12 файл**ов**
  - английский: 5 seconds remains
  - русский: осталось 5 секунд
  - английский: 5 files and 2 directories copied
  - русский: скопировано 5 файл**ов** и 2 каталог**а**
- Разные языки имеют разное представление о форматировании чисел, дат, денежных сумм и т. п. Например, в английском принята точка как разделитель десятичных знаков, немцы и французы используют запятую, итальянцы могут использовать апостроф. Дата 2/3/4 в США означает третье февраля 2004 года и т. д.

Comment: Задачу поставил сам для себя. Строки храню как в android с помощью XML. Да, фел конечно что в Unity3D нету подобных средств из коробки и приходится писать костыли для реализации таких базовых возможностей. В любом случае спасибо за ответ, подчеркнул важные моменты в организации хранения строк.

Comment: @HolyMonkey: разницы-то особой нет: в Android строки в XML, в WPF в ResourceDictionary (XAML). (Насчёт Unity не знаю.)

Comment: В Unity3D вообще ни чего не предусмотрено. Только в Android не нужно DLL создавать и всё ограничивается папками с постфиксами :) очень удобно в плане добавления новых строк.

Comment: @HolyMonkey: создание DLL можно (то есть, нужно) автоматизировать, это не большой вопрос. В любом случае, локализация — немаленькая проблема. Удачи вам в её решении!

Answer (score 3):

Если я вас правильно понял, то можно попробовать использовать упоминавшиеся вами методы расширения. Однако в их случае необходимо помнить, что они - не более чем ситнтаксический сахар, который не изменяет сам класс, к которому применяется данный метод. 
Например:

```
// Набор доступных языков
public enum Language
{
    Russiam,
    English,
    French
}

// Вспомогательный класс, реализующий логику перевода
public static class Translator
{
    public static string Translate(string str, Language lang)
    {
        // что-то там
    }

}

// класс для реализациии метода расширения
public static class Extension
{
    собственно сам метод расширения
    public static string WithLocale(this string str, Language locale)
    {
        return Translator.Translate(str, locale);
    }
}
```

Пользоваться так:

```
string SomeStr = "check_button_text";    
print(SomeStr.WithLocale(Language.Russian));   // вывод русскоязычного варианта  
print(SomeStr.WithLocale(Language.English));   // вывод англоязычного варианта
```

Недостатком этого подхода является то, что вы вынуждены вызывать метод WithLocale, но это, я думаю, не очень большая плата.

Как вариант можно еще создать некий класс, расширяющий функциональность стандартного String. Однако System.String - закрытый класс, поэтому наследование от него невозможно. Следовательно, нужно будет сделать новый класс, включающий в себя некое поле string и умеющий форматировать строку в зависимости от введенного языка. Для него понадобится реализация оператора implicit для неявного приведения к строке и обратно.

Comment: Как раз таки нашел для себя частично подходяшее решение.Класс, с перегруженным оператором неявного приведения типа, и с событием смены локализации для того что бы пользовательский код когда надо в юнетевских классах сам заменил текст. Тут проблема не в том, что код перегружается дополнительными вызовами методов, а в том что такая строка должна прекрасно себя чувствовать везде где её используют так как реализацию библиотек для которых пишу код изменять нельзя.