# Изменение языка приложения (Смена классов)

Tags: c#, wpf

Пытаюсь реализовать метод переключения языка,создала dll, в которой есть два класса enEN.cs и  ruRU.cs

```
public const string NAME_ELEMENT = "НАЗВАНИЕ ЭЛЕМЕНТА";
```

Не могу понять, как создать класс, который бы менял значения строк моей формы, исходя из того языка, что я выбираю? Если сохранять дефолтное значение в какой то файле - то изначально его нужно создавать при загрузке формы. Так же нужно сохранять значение языка, который выберет пользователь.

Подключение строки в элемент:

```
label.Content = EN.String;
label.Content = RU.String;
```

Как я могу сделать это проще? Форма должа загружать (например) RU.String; первее, а при выборе другого варианта менять все подобные значения в форме на EN.String; ..

Comment: DynamicResource + ResourceDictionary. Где-то тут был уже такой вопрос.

Comment: Если честно, я задала этот вопрос, потому что не могу придумать - как сохранить настройку языка, чтобы программа, прочитав файл, поняла что ей нужно загрузить библиотеку с классом (напр. enEN) а при выборе языка загружать другой класс библиотеки. у меня нет идей, решила посоветоваться

Comment: Сохранение настройки — это отдельный вопрос. Динамическое переключение в рантайме сложнее.

Comment: Вот [неплохой подход](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/tomershamam/2007/10/30/wpf-localization-on-the-fly-language-selection/) для переключения языка в рантайме в WPF.

Comment: Пришла к выводу, что нужен класс, который проверит CurentCulture и исходя из полученного результата загрузит тот или иной класс.. только не понимаю как после его вывести для элементов

Comment: Гляньте сюда: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/262848/10105

Comment: @VladD, а классический [gettext](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/C_0023.html) в си-шарпе «некошерен»?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin: Ну, зависит от UI-фреймворка. Для WPF получается слишком много ручной работы, все строки приходится либо получать в code-behind (а это длинно и неидиоматично), либо писать какие-то свои классы вместо `TextBlock`'а (это основной конрол для вывода текста) и пытаться заставить всех их использовать. И так, и так получается не очень. А решение с `DynamicResource` позволяет писать более-менее идиоматичный код.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin: И ещё, решение с gettext требует, чтобы при динамической смене языка код сам обновлял строки. Это может быть сложно, потому что нужно «достучаться» до всех источников текста. Решение с DynamicResource обновляет тексты автоматически. Но есть всё равно стандартные проблемы с составными текстами, для них нужны свои велосипеды. :-(

Comment: @VladD, *решение с gettext требует, чтобы при динамической смене языка код сам обновлял строки* — динамическая смена языка — это тоже какая-то си-шарп-специфика? просто впервые о таком слышу. использование gettext-а, насколько мне известно, не требует такого «зверства», да и с трудом себе представляю, как такое можно реализовать.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin: Ну, если вы запустили программу, она показала UI, и вдруг юзер говорит — хочу переключить с английского на русский. Не заставлять же его перезапускать программу? Вот и приходится обновлять все строки на лету.

Comment: @VladD, ага, понятно. это ms/windows-специфика. в unix локаль — это свойство процесса. и чтобы процесс заработал с другим свойством, его, естественно, надо **пере**запустить.

Comment: Вот тут еще вариант https://habrahabr.ru/post/256193/

Comment: @VladD, подскажите, почему именно ResourceDictionary, а не обычные ресурсы (*.resx)?

Comment: @Vlad: Их в таком виде легко подменять в рантайме, если все тексты подключаются через `DynamicResource`. С resx, строки приходится обновлять вручную.

Answer (score 2):

Если хочется делать локализацию через файлы (чего я не советую делать), то можно так:

```
 public interface ILocalization
 {
     string NameLabelText {get;}
     string LastNameLabelText {get;}
 }

 public class RuLocalization : ILocalization
 {
      public string NameLabelText {get;} = "Имя";
      public string LastNameLabelText {get;} = "Фамилия"
 }

 public class EnLocalization : ILocalization
 {
      public string NameLabelText {get;} = "Name";
      public string LastNameLabelText {get;} = "LastName"
 }

 public class View
 {
      public View(ILocalization Localization)
      {
          labelName.Content = Localization.NameLabelText; 
          labelLastName.Content = Localization.LastNameLabelText; 
      }
 }
```

Я бы рекомендовал использовать готовый framework. https://www.codeproject.com/kb/wpf/wpf_resx_localization.aspx